# iOS: Can someone explain CFDictionaryRef for me?

Tags: ios, addressbook

I'm doing some testing on AddressBook and though I can get the data I am looking for I'm curious about how it is delivered. Specifically CFDictionaryRef. When I cast this to a NSDictionary and log to console I just get a string value, not a key=value pair. If I try to log allKeys my test app breaks.

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
if ([contactName isEqualToString:ownerName]) { 

                    //get reference to  their email addresses
                    ABMultiValueRef contactEmails = ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty);

                    //loop
                    for (NSUInteger e = 0; e < ABMultiValueGetCount(contactEmails); e++){

                        CFDictionaryRef thisPersonCFEmailDict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(contactEmails, e);
                        NSDictionary* thisPersonEmailDict = (__bridge NSDictionary*)thisPersonCFEmailDict;

                        NSLog(@"%@", [thisPersonEmailDict allKeys]);

                    }

                }
```

Comment: What makes you think `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex()` returns a `CFDictionaryRef`? It's documented as returning a `CFTypeRef`, which is the CoreFoundation equivalent of `id`.

Comment: Nothing, I'm in the learning curve stage of this and just seeing what I can do. I was looking at a couple of SO post on the topic and pulling some snippets to see what worked. Thanks for the answer, that clears up my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex()` returns a `CFDictionaryRef`. It doesn't. It returns whatever value is appropriate for that multi-value, as evidenced by the `CFTypeRef` return value.

You can use `ABMultiValueGetPropertyType()` to find out what type of value a particular multi-value record has. If that returns `kABDictionaryPropertyType` then you know it's a dictionary, but in your case it's probably returning `kABStringPropertyType`. It could also return `kABInvalidPropertyType`, which may indicate that the multi-value contains different types. If so, you'll need to resort to using `CFGetTypeID()` to identify the type of value returned from `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex()`.

Comment: Thanks, this answer makes things even clearer than your comment above.

Answer (score 1):

CFDictionaryRef is the Core Foundation counterpart of NSDictionary. Because NSDictionary and CFDictionary are “toll-free bridged,” you can substitute a CFDictionary object for a NSDictionary object in your code (with appropriate casting). Although they are corresponding types, CFDictionary and NSDictionary do not have identical interfaces or implementations, and you can sometimes do things with **CFDictionary** that you cannot easily do with **NSDictionary**. Toll-free bridging, means that you can use the same data type as the parameter to a Core Foundation function call or as the receiver of an Objective-C message.